# My photos disappeared after reprogramming my iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I have a huge problem. My iPhone 4 went off and went to a service to fix it. I said to him that I have too many photos there and he should be careful. He said he reprogrammed my iPhone, and when I turned on the phone all my photos and apps were **deleted**. I had my entire life there, is there **any way** to get at least my photos back.

To be clear, I have never done any back up with iCloud or iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you [don't have a backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47179/iphone-4-is-it-possible-to-do-a-photo-recovery-for-photos-without-a-previous-b), you will want to put the phone in airplane mode and stop using the device. Then see what companies do data recovery from iPhones.

It is trickier than recovering data from a hard drive since SSD/flash storage allocates things differently than a sector based disk does. Also, the passcode and pairing procedure make mounting the raw storage harder.

You should expect to pay some $$ for the service. The specific model of iOS and hardware will increase or decrease the cost as will your location in the world and if you need quick service vs sending it off to a lower cost location for the recovery work.

Comment: I dont care about the money, trust me. But I dont know where to go? Here in Albania,I went at all services that I thought it would help me. Can you help me with any name of a company that makes this data recovery? And thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @Kle  Try https://www.krollontrack.com/services/data-recovery/mobile/ and then see if any places in Europe are similar.